# Need help: Forum for Receiver Design queries

Tags: matlab, wireless, fpga, wifi, gnuradio

As much as I love this forum for my programming related questions, I am finding little or no help here. I am working on designing a **Receiver for WLAN** and have have lot of queries and I am looking for a forum where I can ask someone who are working in the same area.

I would be glad if you could suggest me where I can post my questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For basic receiver design, you may want to have a look at our sister site, [electronics.stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Also, [Signal, Image & Video Processing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1691/signal-image-video-processing) might be of help once it gets off the ground.

Also, when you're working in a specific field with which programmers in general are not very familiar, you have to explain your questions very well in terms that everybody understands. To give you an example:

> In 802.11b, Barker Code is used for spreading.

is completely incomprehensible for me, and, sorry, I don't have the time to fire up Wikipedia and order textbooks from our library to teach myself the specifics of how WLANs work.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will ask questions at electronics.stackexchange.com. Stackoverflow will remain my favorite for programming related queries.